# i want to make the dashed lines responsive(fits to window) when the size of the window changes?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]When i am decreasing the window size, then it is having same width and height. i am using those dashed lines for instructions.
That dashed line is lying between two div's(say rectangular boxes).
my requirement is to make an adjustment between those two div's in an appropriate way.
    visit https://codepen.io/himabindukalla/pen/pBWLRP?

```
<svg height="80" width="300" class="pausedLine layout horizontal ">
          <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
            <path stroke-dasharray="12,12" d="M5 40 l450 0" />
          </g>
        </svg>
        <svg height="80" width="300" class="diceLine">
          <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
            <path stroke-dasharray="12,12" d="M5 40 l250 0" />
          </g>
        </svg>

        <svg height="120" width="300" class="crossedLine">
          <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
            <path stroke-dasharray="12,12" d="M5 40 l250 555" />
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: can you show some code? what you have tried?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want can you please upload your code

Comment: You can try giving width and height in %

Comment: its not working. because height and width are overwritten in svg tag

Comment: I can't see any `div`s in your sample

Comment: pause button and  instructions are the div's which haven't represented in code.

Comment: Do you need to connect two divs with an svg path?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear how you want it all to act together – but when it comes to SVS's and responsive I recommend you to look into the following attributes:

1. viewBox
2. preserveAspectRatio
3. vector-effect

**Example:**

The SVG will be horizontally responsive taking up 50% of the screen width while locked to a height of 1px. The viewBox allows the SVG to scale and the preserveAspectRatio allows it to scale without width and height being locked together. The vector-effect prevents the stroke from scaling (keeping the line at 1px height). I hope this can point you in the right direction :)

```html
<svg height="1" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 12 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 l12 0" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="1" 
        stroke-dasharray="6,6" 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        />
</svg>
```

**Update**

Example using simple floats two responsive and one fixed sized SVS's

```css
svg, div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.dia {
  position:relative;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="top" height="1" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 12 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 l12 0" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="1" 
        stroke-dasharray="6,6" 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        />
</svg>
<div>
  CONTENT
</div>
<svg class="bot" height="1" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 12 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 l12 0" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="1" 
        stroke-dasharray="6,6" 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        />
</svg>
<svg class="dia" height="24" width="24">
  <path d="M0 0 l18 24" 
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="1" 
        stroke-dasharray="6,6" 
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        />
</svg>
```

Comment: I've made a small update to the snippet – to better illustrate how viewBox width and stroke-dasharray should match